# Laravel/Lumen - Serializar un objeto

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php5

Buenas tengo 2 modelos en mi proyecto de Lumen , uno es Cars  y el otro Users , la relación que tengo definida es que 1 user puede tener N Cars

Modelo User

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as 
AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as 
AuthorizableContract;
use App\Traits\ActiveOrInactiveModelTrait;
use App\Traits\UserModelTrait;

class User extends Model implements 
AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, JWTSubject
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, ActiveOrInactiveModelTrait, UserModelTrait;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'status'
];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
];


/**
 * Get all cars created by a user.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function pages_created()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Cars', 'created_by');
}

}
```

Modelo Cars

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Traits\ActiveOrInactiveModelTrait;
use App\Traits\PageModelTrait;

class Cars extends Model
{
use ActiveOrInactiveModelTrait, PageModelTrait;

protected $fillable = [
    'title',
'brand',
    'created_by',
    'updated_by',
    'status',
];

public $relationships = array('creator');

/**
 * Get the user who created the car.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function creator()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'created_by');
}

}
```

Tengo un controlador que hago un getCarsFromUser que recibe como parametro el id de User y luego en el controlador hago algo como esto

```
    try {
        $user = User::find($id);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'data' => new \stdClass(),
            'response_text' => $e->getMessage()
        ], 500);
    }

    if ($user === null)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'data' => new \stdClass(),
            'response_text' => 'Resource Not Found'
        ], 404);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $user,
        'response_text' => 'OK'
    ], 200);
```

En principio si encuentra el usuario me lo devuelve junto con las propiedades del modelo juntamente con una respuesta 200, si el ID es nulo me devuelve una respuesta 400.

Esto funciona , lo unico que cuando me devuelve la propiedad car me devuelve un array de car , es decir car [1,3,11] , que son los ids del modelo car relacionados con este usuario.

Lo que intengo hacer es al devolver el JSON es devolver todos los datos del usuario juntamente con todos los datos de cada coche , esa es la duda.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega los modelos User y Car, y sus migraciones respectivas.

Comment: Gracias , he puesto los modelos pero no me ha pillado el formato. A ver si un administrador me lo puede editar. Gracias

Comment: No veo la relación definida en tus modelos ¿o estoy entendiendo mal?

Comment: @ilernet  Puedes utilizar el método `with()` para para que traiga los datos directamente. Es decir `$user = User::where('id', $id)->with('relacion')->get();`   puedes revisar la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Gracias @Xerif , solucionado tal como dijiste. gracias

Comment: @ilernet te añado respuesta para que puedas marcarlo como solucionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como podemos ver en la documentación (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) Laravel por defecto no carga los datos de las relaciones hasta que no son necesarios.

Por ejemplo para el caso de la pregunta

```
// Obtenemos la fila, pero no los datos de sus relaciones
$user = User::find($id); 

// Al recorrer la relación es cuando se obtienen los datos
foreach ( $user->relacion as $fila) {
    echo $fila->campo;
}
```

Es oportuno indicar que en el caso anterior Laravel hará **1 + N consultas**, es decir una consulta para obtener el registro principal y una consulta más para cada fila de la relación.

Hay caso en los que nos interesa obtener todos los datos del tirón, sin esperar a que estos sean necesarios o recorridos o si sabemos de antemano que todos los datos de la relación van a ser necesarios.

Para estos casos podemos utilizar el método `with()` de Laravel. Esto nos traerá todos los datos de la fila y su relación en solo **2 consultas**.

Ejemplo

```
 $user = User::where('id', $id)->with('relacion')->get();
```

En este caso los datos de la relación serán traídos inmediatamente después de traer la fila del modelo User